# Java - Retrieve next 50 results

Tags: java, json, pagination

```
rob = response.getJSONObject();

array = rob.getJSONArray("data");
fr = new ArrayList();
int count = array.length();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

       friend = array.getJSONObject(i);
       fr.add(friend.get("name"));

}
```

Here `fr` is my array list.

I want to select first 50 result from output names.

Then next 50 result from output and then next 50, so on until all response ends.

Is there any way I can do that ? Itrate or For loop ?

```
for(int i = 0; i<fr.size(); i++){
   System.out.print(fr[i]+",")
   if(i%5==0) System.out.println();
}
```

Tried above code but result in untable some time it select one some time all .

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < fr.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(fr[i]+",");
    if ((i + 1) % 50 == 0) { // You have to use i + 1 because otherwise the modulo logic won't work
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Working but if remaining only 1 response it prints 5 again ? how is that ?

Comment: @Vince I don't understand your problem. Can you give an example?

Comment: If I am getting 560 responses. What will be the last print here it should  be last 10 after 550 responses ?

Comment: If `fr.size()`==560 you will get 11 Lines with 50 elements and the last line has 10 elements.